# I am trying to fetch data with Unsplash in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have done to set the code like this, but whenever i execute the code i recieve an error, how can i fix the error

```
import React from 'react';

const ImageList = props => {
    const image = props.images.map((image) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={image.urls.regular} />
            </div>
        )
    });

    return <div>{image}</div>
};

export default ImageList;
```

The error i receive in the following :

```
Line 5:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
Compiling...
Compiled with warnings.
```

Comment: I think the error message is quite self-explanatory. Do you understand it?

Comment: Some explanation for that error can be found here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/

Comment: i think this a warning @ChrisR when i try to get the data the result an exist

Comment: @tenor528 thank youu i must read first

Answer (score 2):

As `ChrisR` and `tenor528` mentioned, it's self-explanatory. You need to add an `alt` attribute to your images. Ideally, your image tag should be like this:

```
<img src="linkToImage" alt="description of Image">
```

`alt` attribute useful for accessibility purposes. For example, when someone is using a screenreader, the `alt` text would be read. That's why ESLint is giving you a warning.

Also, it is mentioned in the error, how to solve it:

1- Either add a description.
2- Put empty string.

So, in your case, if you are not getting the description in the props, replace

```
<img src={image.urls.regular} />
```

with

```
<img src={image.urls.regular} alt="" />
```

While if you are getting the description, to simply put that in your alt tag like `alt={image.description}`.